# ALB Target groups showing Unhealthy, though my application is running fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I have microservices deployed in containers, which are running fine and we are able to access with ALBendpoint/microservice.

But my target group which attached to ALB is showing the "Unhealthy" status.

Errors in AWS console:
None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target. Requests are being routed to all targets.
Health checks failed with these codes: [404]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but I am not sure even when a health check fails how the application is running fine. The below answers do not point to the reason and instead are just the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I am seeing two issues here.

1. **Why the application is running fine when the healthcheck fails**. here is the explanation from AWS Docs:

> If a target group contains only unhealthy registered targets, the load balancer nodes route requests across its unhealthy targets. [Health checks for your target groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)

2. **How could you fix the health check while the instances are draining because of failed healthchecks.**

`404` means that the health check URL is not found. Confirm the health check configuration. your health check URL should respond `HTTP 200 OK` response. If your instances are draining repeatedly, you can temporarily set the health check rule to match `HTTP 404` until your instances becomes healthy. Once you figure out the correct health check URL, you can set that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My health check url is default path : /

Comment: do you have a default page served on `/`? whats the status code that it returns

Comment: Its not ablout default page i suspect ALB checks on 80/443 but my tomcat container app on 8080 port so seems its unable to pass health check ..

Comment: You should be able to definetely change the port from the health check page.

Comment: how did you go?

Comment: It works fine with my application health check path,

Comment: What is that port guys!!? I added All Trafic from Anywhere and Target Group still Unhealthy, I'm pretty sure that I did everything like docs but still 502 Bad Gateway :)

Comment: @ArunK You are pointing to the solution to the problem in the above answer but can you elaborate on what could be a reason for the problem. If the health check fails the target should not be registered and the application should send 502 bad gateway but in this case the application is responding.

Comment: The question is more likely the micro services are running fine when you access them directly , but not working through the ALB. When the micro services working fine while the target group shows the targets unhealthy, usually it  might be an issue with the health check configuration.

Comment: No that's not what the question says. The user was able to access the microservice using ALB url also even when the health check failed. @LakshmiReddy correct me if I am wrong

Comment: ok first of all, you are right about that application was accessible from ALB. sorry about that. I have updated my answer. Let me the know whether or not the point one satisfies you.

Comment: Only issue with leaving it to 404 response is that soon your access log will be filled with 404 requests coming in from AWS Healthcheck requests. generally only non 200 response are logged in access log by default

Answer (score 3):

In my case IIS server and resolved with the below steps.

1. Check the security groups - whether we have opened the required ports from ALB SG to EC2 SG.
2. > Login to server and check does IIS server's default site has 443 port opened if your health-check is on 443. (whatever port you are using for health checks).

Use the curl command to troubleshoot the issue.

1. If you would like to check on HTTPS use the below command to check the response. Use -k or --insecure to ignore the SSL issue.

   curl https://[serverIP] -k
2. For HTTP test use the below command.

   curl http://[serverIP]

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason fo this could be that ALB can not access the EC2 containers. I faced a similar issue in which my Drupal application was running but target group was showing unhealthy.
To resolve this, please check whether you have added ALB's security group on port 80 in EC2's security group.
By doing this, the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this issue for 1 day. I finally realized that I had removed the default server configuration from nginx.
this is needed to for de default path that the healthCheck checks